# React-Scroll Library: Active Style Not Applied on 'About' and 'Skill' Buttons Click"

Tags: arrays, rxjs, react-router, javascript-objects, infinite-scroll

I'm currently working with the 'react-scroll' library and have utilized the methods activeClass="active" . The intention behind this is to apply CSS styles from the class 'active' when clicking on my items. However, IActive Style Not Being Applied on 'About' and 'Skill' Button Clicks

```
export const navLinks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Home",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "About",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Porfolio",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "Skill",
  },
];
```

Menu

```
const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="nav">
        <ul className="ul">
          {navLinks.map((link) => (
            <li key={link.id}>
              <Link
                to={link.text}
                activeClass="active"
                spy={true}
                smooth={true}
                duration={500}
              >
                <a className="item" href="#">
                  {link.text}
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Components

```
const about = () => {
  return (
    <div className="divAbout" id="About">
      About
    </div>
  );
};

const skill = () => {
  return (
    <div className="divSkill" id="Skill">
      Skill
    </div>
  );
};
```

Styles

```
.active {
  background-color: #05bd0b;
  
}
```

Comment: Can you also create a fiddle or a snippet where the problem is reproduced?

Comment: Share the complete code.

Comment: The complete code.